# Setting up the Probability Distribution for Independent Events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let E, F, G, H be 4 independent events with probability Pr(E) = 0.2, Pr(F) = 0.4, Pr(G) = 0.6 and Pr(H) = 0.8. Let the random variable be the number of these events that occur.

a) find the distribution of X.

b) find the expectation of X.

So for my distribution: (Does anybody know how to create a table to display information easier?)

$x=0,1,2,3,4$

$P(X=x)=$ of each event.

I can figure out $P(0)=P(4)=.2*.4*.6*.8$ But the probability of 1 event, should I do $4 \choose 1$$*???$ I have no idea what the probability would multiply by. I know once I solve that, its complement or it will be the same as $P(3)$. Then same goes for $P(2)$=$4\choose 1$$*???$

Comment: What does the random variable $X$ denote?

Comment: the number of events that occur from my understanding of reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You only need one more probability, say the probability of $1$ event. Symmetry and sum equal to $1$ take care of the rest.

**One event** can happen in $4$ ways, yes, no, no, no and the other three. The probability of yes, no, no, no is $(0.2)(0.6)(0.4)(0.2)$. The three others are similar, add up.

Answer (score 1):

For $x = 1$, you need to figure out the probability of each single event happening. The probability of $E$ and $E$ alone happening would be $P(E)(1 - P(F))(1 - P(G))(1 - P(H))$, since $E$ needs to happen, while $F, G,$ and $H$ all must not happen. You can write the compound probability as a product, since they're all independent.

Not that this is $P(E \text{ only})$, while you're interested in

$$P (x = 1) = P(E \text{ only}) + P(F \text{ only}) + P(G \text{ only}) + P(H \text{ only}),$$ since the above scenarios are mutually exclusive.

As the other (very good) answer to this question points out, you can get $P(x = 2)$ once you know $P(x = 1)$.